# Variable declared as const within page.evaluate() is not being used in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, constants

I've got a function which works great on a standard browser (ie, firefox, chrome,...) but some part of it doesn't with PhantomJS.

So, I have a file - let name it script1.js - which looks like this :

```
const CONST1 = 1;

function f1()
{
    //...
    myVar = (typeof myVar === "undefined") ? CONST1 : myVar;
    //...
}
```

And here is a sample of the script run by PhantomJS:

```
var page = webPage.create();

page.open(url,function(status){ 
    if (page.injectJs('script1.js')) {
        page.evaluate(function(){
            //...
            f1();
            //...
        });
    }
});
```

Using PhantomJS, if `myVar` is not set, it doesn't takes the value of `CONST1` and still undefined. Indeed, `CONST1`'s value is undefined. If I change for :

```
myVar = (typeof myVar == "undefined") ? "value" : myVar;
```

`myVar` will be "value".

Is there a way to use constants with PhantomJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS supports the `const` keyword with the same behavior as `var`. This means that you can re-assign variables that are declared as `const`. The following code works as-is in PhantomJS 1.9.7 and 2.0.0.

phantomscript.js

```
var page = require("webpage").create();

page.open("http://example.com",function(status){ 
    if (page.injectJs('inc.js')) {
        console.log("out: " + page.evaluate(function(){
            f1();

            return myVar;
        }));
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

inc.js

```
const CONST1 = 1;

function f1()
{
    myVar = (typeof myVar === "undefined") ? CONST1 : myVar;
}
```

output

```
$ phantomjs phantomscript.js
out: 1
```

I suspect the issue was that you were trying to access `CONST1` outside of the page context. PhantomJS has two contexts with the page context being *sandboxed*. What happens in the page context, stays in the page context (except if you explicitly pass it outside). I suggest that you read the documentation to [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) carefully.

There is also a nice picture in the CasperJS documentation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of this "multi contextualization". So what I needed to do was to add `CONST1` in the page environment. So now my function send to the page within the `evaluate()` function can see it.

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS doesn't really support ES6 (ES2015) features as of yet. It will come when the new V8 integration arrives (which i think it did already so i'm hoping soon).

[Here is an open defect on github (it talks about karma but gives you an idea)](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/46) and also there are [plenty of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736114/how-to-use-es6-with-phantomjs) on how to use ES6 with PhantomJS.