# PhantomJS: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>"

Tags: phantomjs

Im currently having problems using phantomJS. Any suggestions?

```
acanyon$ babel-node source_parser.js http://url

/Users/.../node/node_modules/phantom/lib/index.js:23
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(new _phantom2.default(args, config)));
                             ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/acanyon/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/acanyon/fashionblog/node/source_parser.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Am I missing a shim for es6? (the remainder of the script is written in es5).

Comment: See some info on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736114/how-to-use-es6-with-phantomjs

Comment: Shims can't handle unknown syntax.

Comment: This compatibility matrix may also help https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ - looks like you're gonna need to transpile.

Answer (score 6):

Phantomjs use ES5, not ES6 ;)

That's why it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

This failure can be eliminated by using phantom versions prior to 2.0.0.
Notice that this is the phantom package and not the phantomjs package that is giving the failure.

if you want to use versions higher than 1.x. you will need to change your code from   page.open(url, function(){})  to page.open(url).then(function(){}).
this is explained very well at [phantom npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) site. Which gives detailed examples of how to do it