# Getting: Error from phantom after upgrading to Node 6

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, upgrade

after upgrading a MEAN stack application from 0.12 to node 6 we get the following error in our process.error log:

```
 package/node_modules/phantom/lib/index.js:23 return new Promise(resolve     => resolve(new _phantom2.default(args, config)));
```

and the process.output shows:

```
  [2016-12-17 16:11:31.785] [ERROR] console - SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

my version of phantomjs 1.9.8

this is the same problem reported previously:

[phantomjs unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163150/phantomjs-syntaxerror-%20unexpected-token)

by some other user, but me being a relative newbie, I did not understand the answer or how it helps me fix the problem.

please direct me to a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This failure can be eliminated by using phantom versions prior to 2.0.0.
Notice that this is the phantom package and not the phantomjs package that is giving the error